# do you want to run or display contents ?: Asked after run chmod -R

Tags: 12.04, permissions, rails

I was getting a strange `Errno::EACCES error permission denied` when I tried to upload photos.

Then I ran `sudo chmod -R 777 /home/user/Projects/myApp/` on a rails project.This command did not solve my problem and now every time when I open a file I get prompted:

```
Do you want to run designers.js.coffee, or display its contents?
```

How can I make this go away?

Answer (score 5):

The command you ran messed up the files' access rights. Unfortunately, there's no easy way to restore the previous state exactly.

Removing the **executable bit** from the files you are trying to open will get rid of the message, though.

**Warning**: This command will remove the executable bit from **all** files in that directory and its subdirectories, so afterwards you might have to add the bit back for files that are supposed to have it.

`find /home/user/Projects/myApp/ -type f -exec chmod -x {} +`